# ¿Puede un "dilema" abarcar más de dos opciones?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, significado, sustantivos, números

Acabo de ver un juego de palabras en inglés usando la voz *trilemma* en vez de *dilemma*. Si nos vamos al DLE, vemos que en español la palabra *dilema* significa:

> **[dilema](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DmQvDQm)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. dilemma, y este del gr. δίλημμα dílēmma, de δι- di- 'di-' y
> λῆμμα lêmma 'premisa'.
> ```
>
> 1. m. Situación en la que es necesario elegir entre dos opciones igualmente buenas o malas.
> 2. m. Fil. Argumento formado por dos proposiciones contrarias disyuntivamente, de tal manera que, negada o concedida cualquiera de las dos, queda demostrada una determinada conclusión.

Tanto su etimología, que contiene el prefijo griego *[di-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DcsCE20)*, 'dos', como su primera acepción (la usual) hacen alusión a dos posibles alternativas entre las cuales hay que escoger, siendo estas igual de buenas o malas.

Pero ¿qué pasa si hay más de dos alternativas? ¿Qué pasa cuando vas a la pastelería y no sabes cuál de los 20 tipos de pasteles escoger? Dado que la definición de *dilema* hace alusión a solo dos opciones, ¿qué palabra habría que usar si hay más? ¿Valdría *trilema*? ¿O *tetralema*? ¿Alguna otra? ¿Se usaría *dilema* con un significado ampliado? ¿Qué palabra se suele usar en la literatura ante este tipo de situaciones?

NOTA: Curioso que en el Merriam-Webster la definición de *[dilemma](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilemma)* solo hace alusión a "una elección difícil" o "desagradable", sin mencionar expresamente que solo deban ser dos. Aunque curiosamente sí definen *[trilemma](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trilemma)* (están más avanzados que nosotros) como un "dilema con tres opciones en vez de dos". Y el diccionario de Oxford [la define](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilemma) de forma similar al DLE pero indicando que pueden ser "dos o más alternativas".

Comment: Para la situación de la pastelería que planteas, lo adecuado es, sin duda, utilizar el axioma de elección de Zermelo

Answer (score 3):

En el uso formal estricto queda claro que un dilema es una situación donde se plantean dos alternativas mutuamente excluyentes, tal como lo indica la etimología. Sin embargo, incluso en textos donde se plantean y ejemplifican dilemas morales aparecen casos donde hay tres o más opciones claramente delimitadas, como [en este caso](https://educrea.cl/los-dilemas-morales/)...

> Imagínate por un momento que te encuentras en la siguiente situación:
>   eres un miembro del Consejo de Seguridad de la ONU que tiene que votar
>   en un asunto de violación sistemática de Derechos Humanos por parte de
>   un Estado. Al frente de éste se encuentra un dictador que impide
>   cualquier tipo de avance democrático en el país, y que además persigue
>   militarmente a ciertas minorías étnicas, contra las cuales está
>   llevando a cabo acciones sistemáticas de genocidio.
>
> En el consejo de Seguridad deberás dar tu voto a una de las siguientes
>   alternativas:
>
> – No intervenir, puesto que el asunto puede considerarse como interno
>   a ese Estado, y cualquier intervención de la ONU podría interpretarse
>   como injerencia en asuntos internos.
>
> – Aprobar un embargo económico, garantizado mediante una vigilancia
>   militar de sus fronteras, aunque los efectos de dicho embargo recaigan
>   mayoritariamente sobre la población civil de ese Estado, gran parte de
>   la cual no apoya al dictador.
>
> – Aprobar una intervención militar en defensa de las minorías étnicas
>   agredidas, aunque esa decisión implique iniciar una guerra donde
>   morirán miles de personas.

También se presentan "dilemas" donde hay dos alternativas posibles, pero donde la situación es tal que claramente estas alternativas no agotan todas las opciones que podrían tomarse en la vida real. Por ejemplo, el [dilema de Heinz](https://es.sott.net/article/57895-Dilemas-eticos-que-son-tipos-y-4-ejemplos-que-te-haran-pensar):

> La mujer de Heinz está enferma de cáncer, y se espera que muera pronto
>   si no se hace nada por salvarla. Sin embargo, existe un medicamento
>   experimental que los médicos creen que puede salvar su vida: una forma
>   de radio que un farmacéutico acaba de descubrir. Aunque esta sustancia
>   es cara, el farmacéutico en cuestión está cobrando muchas veces más
>   cantidad de dinero de lo que le cuesta producirla (le cuesta 1.000
>   dólares y cobra 5.000). Heinz reúne todo el dinero que puede para
>   comprarla, contando con la ayuda y el préstamo de dinero de todos sus
>   conocidos, pero solo alcanza a reunir 2.500 dólares de los 5.000 que
>   cuesta el producto. Heinz acude al farmacéutico, a quien le dice que
>   su esposa se muere y a quien le pide que le venda el medicamento a
>   menor precio o que le deje pagar la mitad más tarde. El farmacéutico
>   sin embargo se niega, aduciendo que debe ganar dinero con él ya que ha
>   sido quien lo ha descubierto. Dicho esto, Heinz se desespera y se
>   plantea robar la medicina. ¿Qué debería hacer?

En artículos periodísticos se habla de "dilema" muy frecuentemente como sinónimo de "problema acuciante que requiere decisiones", "problema que no puede dejarse sin resolver", "problema cuyas posibles soluciones tienen todas un lado negativo", etc. Si observamos cómo es traducido *[dilema](https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/dilema.html)* al inglés en textos reales, veremos que contiene todas estas acepciones y no sólo la de dilema filosófico formal.

A partir de todo esto me da la impresión de que "dilema" tiene dos significados: cuando se habla del mismo como de un problema planteado, es más claro que significa "problema con dos alternativas de solución excluyentes"; pero cuando nos referimos a la situación real, usamos "dilema" también como "problema con varias vías total o parcialmente excluyentes de solución".